# Как сделать такое модальное окно?

Tags: html

Модальное окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/Fakt_37/hhb92Le7/1/

```
<div class="panel-heading"><!-- IF IS_ADMIN --> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manage_user">[Администрирование]</a><!-- ENDIF --></div>
<!-- IF IS_ADMIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="manage_user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Администрирование</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="admin">
                <button onclick="ajax.exec({action : 'manage_user', mode: '<!-- IF USER_ACTIVE -->user_deactivate<!-- ELSE -->user_activate<!-- ENDIF -->', user_id : {PROFILE_USER_ID}}); return false;" class="btn btn-link">Деактивировать</button>
                <button onclick="ajax.exec({action : 'manage_user', mode: 'delete_profile', user_id : '{PROFILE_USER_ID}'}); return false;" class="btn btn-link">Удалить этого пользователя</button>
                <button onclick="ajax.exec({action : 'manage_user', mode: 'delete_topics', user_id : '{PROFILE_USER_ID}'}); return false;" class="btn btn-link">Удалить все сообщения пользователя</button>
                <button onclick="ajax.exec({action : 'manage_user', mode: 'delete_message', user_id : '{PROFILE_USER_ID}'}); return false;" class="btn btn-link">Удалить все сообщения, кроме заглавных</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Запретить пользователю</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="tLeft" style="padding: 2px 6px 6px; display: block;" id="user-opt">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_avatar"/>Показывать аватар</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_sig"/>Показывать подпись</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_passkey"/>Скачивать торренты</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_pm"/>Отправлять ЛС</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_post"/>Отправлять сообщения</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_post_edit"/>Редактировать сообщение</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="dis_topic"/>Создавать темы</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Сохранить изменения</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Я приложил скрин, приложил пример работы окна, куда еще развернутей?

Comment: например, напишите **что именно** не работает в вашем пример, какое ожидаемое поведение

Comment: это, небольшое отступление, а вы знаете что на jsfiddle - в настройках можно выбрать некоторые библиотеки, а те которые нельзя можно подключить как external file - просто сейчас большая часть кода - это библиотеки, и вашего кода вообще не видно.